# How can I stop my computer from restarting?

Tags: drivers

I had Windows 8.1 and upgraded to Windows 10. With both operating systems, I ran into trouble ever since I hooked up my Wacom tablet. My computer freezes and then this screen appears.

[image]

I thought that maybe it was a problem with my Wacom, so I hooked it up to another computer just to be sure. It appears it is not the problem, because it works fine on another one. Perhaps it's a driver issue. When I was using Windows 8.1 with my original computer, I would keep getting this message.

[image]

Perhaps I had bad drivers, and the Wacom put more stress on them. Does this sound like this could be the problem? What do you think, and how do I fix it?

Here are the specs of the computer I want to fix.

- AMD Quad-Core Processor A4-5000
- 17.3 HD+ Acer CineCrystal LED LCD
- AMD Radeon HD 8330
- 8 GB DDR3 L Meomeroy
- 1000 GB HDD
- 802.11b/n + BT
- 6-cell Li-ion battery

Comment: What exact version of your driver are you running for your graphics card and for your wacom tablet?

Comment: @Brian, was Display driver crashing in Windows 8.1 as well ? There seems to be no driver available for Windows 10

Comment: I don't know what the exact version of my driver is, and yes, the crash happened with Windows 8.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wacom has released a new build, ISD_7.3.1-7, which provides compatibility for Windows 10.

It is recommended to run the **WacomHardwareCheck** Utility first to ensure the proper driver is downloaded for your device. The utility can be downloaded here: http://cdn.wacom.com/U/drivers/TabletPC/WacomHardwareCheck.exe

The new driver can be downloaded here: http://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/ should you wish to download it directly, however it is recommended to run the WacomHardwareCheck Utility first.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did that first step, and it turns out that my driver is outdated, as the window from that second link shows. Before I install the latest driver, it says to uninstall the other one first, but I can't seem to do so. When I try uninstalling Tablet Driver V8, I get this error message.

"The Setupext.Inf file cannot be found. Please verify the distribution diskette."

Is it okay to install the new drivers anyway?